# Sandbox Xcode issues

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

I spent hours in forums to try to figure out what is the issue. I have an Apple developer account and configures a test user (Sandbox) - I have a check next to my user which I believe means it's created and should work. But I cannot use it. On my phone I don't see even the sandbox title under iTunes & App Store it's like I miss the capability in my application. There are many complaints about Sandboxing usage on Xcode but nothing that helped me out.
**What do I need to check or add to make the Sandbox work?**

Comment: Unclear what you are asking for. Are you talking about sandbox account in AppStore connect to test purchases? Or are you aksing for the sandbox that prevents your app interfering with other apps? Is your app on iOS or macOS? What kind of capabilities are you asking for? What do you mean by the sandbox title under iTunes and App Store?

Comment: It concerns Sandbox to test In App Purchase for an IOS app I am developing. Apple ask to test intensively the IAP via a Sandbox solution. The problem is that I configured the app bundleID, Product ID and information in App Store Connect. I added as well a Sandbox user for those tests that has been validated. I added the IAP code in my App (SKPayment related functions) but when I do a basic App purchase test I cannot log in with my Sandbox user. Neither when I connect to my Iphone -> Settings -> ITunes & App Store -> I should see here the sandbox menu but I don't see any menu about Sandbox.